# Angular 10 - tsconfig.base.json file is not generated after upgrading to angular 10

Tags: angular-cli, tsconfig, angular10

I just successfully upgraded the old angular version of my project from 4 to 10 and noticed that the tsconfig.base.json file was not generated as indicated in the angular upgrade guide:

https://update.angular.io/?v=4.4-10.0

I also created a fresh angular 10 project to check if the file will be generated from there and it seems that its the same from the project I upgraded

I wonder when are tsconfig.base.json are created and why it is indicated in the guide that this file will be generated when it actually did not upon upgrading to or creating a new angular 10 project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there were a series of issues that this "solution style tsconfig" approach introduced, so they've decided to (at least temporarily) roll it back.

From Angular's GitHub:

> Hi @xiaoxiangmoe,
> Following numerous issues, we have discussed this internally and with the TypeScript team at Microsoft decided that for a better DX it's best to revert and remove solution style tsconfig.
>
> We are not excluding that in the future we re-introduce solution tsconfig.

Source [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18616).

Read more [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eB6cGCG_2ircfS5GzpDC9dBgikeYYcMxghVH5sDESHw/edit).